# Need to cycle images with setInterval ( ) using start and stop buttons. (only using javascript0

Tags: javascript

Sorry for being a total newb. This is my 1st week on this javascript crashcourse and I know noobs are annoying as hell. Anyway, I couldn't get your suggestions to work. I tried some different things and got it to work, but now, once I press "Stop Slideshow," I can't get the slideshow to start again from where it left off (or at all). Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="http://joemiller.us/wp-content/uploads/beautiful-birds-wallpapers_blue-bird-wallpaper-free.jpg" alt="Birds" id="image" style="height: 200px; width: 200px">
        <br>
        <button type="button" onclick="startShow()">Start Slideshow</button>    
        <button type="button" onclick="stopShow()">Stop Slideshow</button>  
    </div>
    <script>
        var images = [
            'http://joemiller.us/wp-content/uploads/beautiful-birds-wallpapers_blue-bird-wallpaper-free.jpg',
            'http://www.hgsitebuilder.com/files/writeable/uploads/hostgator172932/image/exoticbirds2.jpg',
            'http://melleum.com/data/uploads/6/280423-birds.jpg',
            'https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTBew8yyadE865lI-dSdg2XgNIREm1RZVhQpzjN3HzmmLwuR0_j',
            'https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSvo3Aew9HAc2PXVaHz9ghtr-_F9D7ZqySzRLbvPwG6mzmMsBaVHQ'
            ];
        var img = document.getElementById('image');
        var i = 0;
        var start = setInterval("cycleImages ()", 3000);
        function cycleImages () {   
            if (i < images.length-1) {
                i++;
            } else {
                i=0;
            }
            img.src = images[i];
        }
        function startShow () {
            start;
        }
        function stopShow () {
            clearInterval(start);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite you appearing to be a bit of a giverupper, here's one way of doing it:

```js
var images = [
  'http://joemiller.us/wp-content/uploads/beautiful-birds-wallpapers_blue-bird-wallpaper-free.jpg',
  'http://www.hgsitebuilder.com/files/writeable/uploads/hostgator172932/image/exoticbirds2.jpg',
  'http://upic.me/i/z2/birds-bird_928268.jpg',
  'http://melleum.com/data/uploads/6/280423-birds.jpg',
  'https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTBew8yyadE865lI-dSdg2XgNIREm1RZVhQpzjN3HzmmLwuR0_j',
  'https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSvo3Aew9HAc2PXVaHz9ghtr-_F9D7ZqySzRLbvPwG6mzmMsBaVHQ'
];
var imageIndex = 0;
var delay = 1000;
var slideshowImage = document.getElementById('slideshow-image');
var startButton = document.getElementById('start');
var stopButton = document.getElementById('stop');
var timer;

startButton.addEventListener('click', start);
stopButton.addEventListener('click', stop);

function start() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  
  slideshowImage.setAttribute('src', images[imageIndex]);
  
  timer = setInterval(function () {
    imageIndex = imageIndex >= (images.length - 1) ? 0 : ++imageIndex;
    slideshowImage.setAttribute('src', images[imageIndex]);
  }, delay);
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(timer);
}
```

```css
#slideshow-image {
  max-width: 320px;
}
```

```html
<div class="controls">
  <button id="start">Start</button>
  <button id="stop">Stop</button>
</div>
<img id="slideshow-image" src="">
```

Comment: Looks good, but I think you should clear the interval before setting it (in case the user clicks the start button twice).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`function*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)'s *next* in a *setInterval's function* after the element `<img src="" id="image" />` exists,

```
var tag = document.getElementById('image'),
    srcs = ['http://google.com/favicon.ico', 'http://www.yahoo.com/favicon.ico', 'http://www.bing.com/favicon.ico'];

function* loop(tag, srcs) {
    var i = 0;
    while (1) {
        yield tag.src = srcs[i++ % srcs.length];
    }
}

var gen = loop(tag, srcs);
setInterval(gen.next.bind(gen), 500);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vav4Lmdc/1/)

Comment: I don't really understand what you guys wrote and I couldn't get it to work that way, but I got it to work a different way. Only now, once I press stop, I can't start the slideshow again.